# My Java drawString commands aren't drawing the text for whatever reason

Tags: java, swing, awt

The text that's supposed to show here isn't showing up in the code for whatever reason.

What it's supposed to look like below:

[image]

The code in question:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class CRlab31 extends Canvas
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    JFrame w=new JFrame("Graphics");
    w.setSize(800,600);
    w.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    CRlab31 canvas=new CRlab31();
    w.add(canvas);
    w.setVisible(true);
  }
  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(50,20,100,200);
    g.fillOval(160,20,100,200);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(200,400,200,20);
    g.drawOval(200,430,200,100);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawString("Graphics are pretty neat.",500,100);
    int x=getWidth()/2;
    int y=getHeight()/2;
    g.drawString("The first letter of this string is at ("+x+","+y+")",x,y);
  }
}
```

Is there anything I should be doing here to make the text actually display like in the example?

Comment: Just tried this code, it is working fine.

Comment: @Berger Same here. Voted to close as *"This question was **caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."*

Comment: Huh. Strange that it isn't working like it should on my end. Could be that I need to tweak the text position a bit to get it to actually show (it does this on a Macintosh, but seems to work fine on a PC).

Comment: Just in case, try to have your class extend `JPanel` to avoid mixing Swing and AWT components, and override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` .

Comment: The first minor edit there seems to have did the trick. Thanks, Berger.

Comment: *"Thanks, Berger."* Tip: Add @Berger (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: In addition to the suggestion by Berger, don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent(...) at the start of the method, to make sure the background gets cleared before you do the custom painting.